# build a dynamic datatable with jquery gives error: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined

Tags: jquery, html-table, datatable

i'm manually building a datatable cycling some query results.
I append name of columns only for the first result, while for other i add only the content row.
That's the code:

```
            for(i=0;i<simulations.length;i++ ) {
            if (i==0) {
                $("#tabella").find('thead')
                    .append($('<tr>')
                        .append("<th scope=\"col\">"+"container name"+"</th>")
                        .append("<th scope=\"col\">"+"simulation date"+"</th>")
                    )
            }
            $("#tabella").find('tbody')
                .append($('<tr>')
                    .append("<td>"+simulations[i].container_name+"</td>")
                    .append("<td>"+simulations[i].simulation_date+"</td>")
                );

            if (sessionStorage.getItem("queryFilters") != null){
                for(var name in queryFilters) {
                    if (!name.endsWith("flag")) {
                        if (i==0) {
                            $("#tabella").find('thead')
                                .find('tr')
                                .append("<th scope=\"col\">"+name.replace(/_/g, ' ')+"</th>")
                        }
                        $("#tabella").find('tbody')
                            .find('tr')
                            .append("<td>"+simulations[i][name]+"</td>")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $('#tabella').DataTable();

            if (sessionStorage.getItem("queryFilters") != null){
                for(var name in queryFilters) {
                    if (!name.endsWith("flag")) {
                        if (i==0) {
                            $("#tabella").find('thead')
                                .find('tr')
                                .append("<th scope=\"col\">"+name.replace(/_/g, ' ')+"</th>")
                        }
                        $("#tabella").find('tbody')
                            .find('tr')
                            .append("<td>"+simulations[i][name]+"</td>")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $('#tabella').DataTable();
```

It's all ok if I have one row as result, or if remove dynamic columns
But if i have two or more rows in the table, i have the following error:

```
jquery-3.5.1.js:4046 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined
at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.js:1176:15)
at Function.each (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js:381:19)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js:203:17)
at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.js:1173:39)
at Function.each (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js:381:19)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js:203:17)
at jQuery.fn.init.DataTable [as dataTable] (https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.js:869:8)
at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.DataTable (https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.js:15214:18)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost/Checks-GreenCharge/resources/js/index.js:160:27)
at mightThrow (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js:3762:29) undefined
jQuery.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4046
jquery-3.5.1.js:4055 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined
    at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:1176)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.5.1.js:381)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-3.5.1.js:203)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:1173)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.5.1.js:381)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-3.5.1.js:203)
    at jQuery.fn.init.DataTable [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.js:869)
    at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.js:15214)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.js:160)
    at mightThrow (jquery-3.5.1.js:3762)
```

Maybe (but i'm not sure) is something related to the ".find('tr')" after first row
Maybe at that time he finds two td elements and doesn't now where to append the th element
I tried to add .last() to find() but it doesn't work...

EDIT FIXED: i was putting the .last() in the wrong place (on thead part)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT FIXED: i was putting the .last() in the wrong place (on thead part)